# Why am I getting a "lens not attached" message on my Nikon camera?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting

I have a Nikon D3100 with the Nikkor 18-55mm lens. Whenever I attach the lens and turn the camera on, its simply saying "lens not attached". The only time it will take a picture is in manual mode *and* its a self timed picture. How can I make my camera work?

Answer (score 2):

You will get this message if the lens barrel is locked; push the lock/unlock button on the lens.  Then extend the lens a bit, and that might take care of the problem---at least it did for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the contacts and reattaching the lens.  If that doesn't work, try a different lens to determine if the lens or the body is the cause of the problem.  Send whichever part is broken to Nikon for repair.